# Scalable method to union all column in a table - Big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | d |

and I want to have only one column, I'd do

```
SELECT col1 FROM TABLE 
UNION ALL 
SELECT col2 FROM TABLE
```

and get

| col1 |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |

But now let's say I have 100 columns (all strings, same data type), what's the best way to add all the columns together without doing a union all for all the columns? I found solutions on SQL server but not working in Big Query.

Comment: Are all your 100 columns of the same data type?

Comment: yes, all strings, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select value
from your_table t,
unnest(bqutil.fn.json_extract_values(to_json_string(t))) value
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]